# Which ways can I use to send NSLogs from user devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, cocoa

guys!
It will be good for me to receive logs when my application gets wrong status code or incorrect data from server in my failure handlers. It there any tools to receive logs remotely from specific devices or maybe from all devices?

Comment: Email, socket, web service. The choice is really yours to make.

Comment: @DCGoD, I agree with you, but it is a hard way that costs a lot of time. On the other hand I want to know is it normal to use remote logging from users. How Apple feels about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack).  This is also a use of analytics (Localytics, Flurry, etc).  Crashalytics and TestFlight SDK will help with this as well.  But for remote logging, something like CocoaLumberjack is likely all you need.

Comment: Thank you, does CocoaLumberjack uses your own server to send logs, am I right?